# Q: Correct way posting JSON from Reactstrap form

Tags: json, reactjs, post, reactstrap

I'd like to get the JSON from a form I created using Reactstrap in order to be able to post it against my backend.

I've found [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/everdimension/c74953456fd8a533b252508d4738733e/raw/3aba30fb151c4beebe9f5e39d324a4f02894cbbe/minimal-react-form.js) example. I want to use Reactstrap so I wasn't able to put an `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}` onto the `Form` component. This is why I thought of replacing the `Form` component with a classic `form` tag but the `FormData` stays empty.

[Here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ouniti/36ab01eb5030a5a7e3bb3bc28f7a5ec3/raw/3b524a5ccc937cc73790676b6c59315e3f9dce24/react-post-form.js) is my code for this.

I appreciate every advice.

Greetings

Comment: You have to use `FormData.get()` to see the result. Try [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kzvsgt?file=index.js)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use Form component from ReactStrap you should place a button with `type="Submit"` for `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}` to work.

Making this change and changing `form` component to `Form` should work.

```
<FormGroup check row>
  <Col sm={{ size: 10, offset: 2 }}>
    <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
  </Col>
</FormGroup>
```

And to get the data you can do

```
 submitForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.target);
    console.log(data.get('author'));
    console.log(data.get('datTo'));
    console.log(data.get('dateFrom'));    
  }
```

Comment: Did I misunderstand you? I tried it like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6gjxxg) but the data is still empty -- makes no difference if it's a form tag either

Comment: Data is not empty, you should use `get('inputName')` to get the desired value.